# Error when installing the package numcodecs. What do I do?

Tags: python, windows, installation, package, command-prompt

I ran this command:

```
pip install numcodecs
```

And I got this error:

```
Error: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\sunit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sunit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-419pmst9\\numcodecs\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sunit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-419pmst9\\numcodecs\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sunit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5lw96050\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\sunit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\numcodecs' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What do I do?

Comment: Try to install it after upgrading your pip using this command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Try running it in VS Code Terminal (PowerShell) instead

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (trying to install zarr module, with the error coming from installing numcodecs). I was able to resolve it by updating my OSX to the newest version (Catalina), which then led to me reinstalling anaconda, Xcode, and previous Python packages from scratch. After doing that,

```
pip install numcodecs
```

still failed with the same error. However,

```
conda install numcodecs
```

or in my case:

```
conda install zarr
```

worked without error. It seems to have something to do with a conflict between Xcode tools and pip installer, which conda overcomes. My colleague was likewise unable to install via pip but could install via conda and a virtual environment on the first try, a faster option to try first before reinstalling everything.

Brief discussion of the issue on Github [here](https://github.com/zarr-developers/numcodecs/issues/236#issuecomment-654548696).